# UIDocumentInteractionController for custom file type - does sending or receiving app have wrong UTI?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager, uti

I'm developing a level editor that will send level files to a game app. I've registered a custom UTI in the game so that it shows up in the `UIDocumentInteractionController` options menu.

However, when I select "Open in MyApp" I get the console error **"Invalid LSOpenOperation request - No applications found to open document"**.

I have tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487469/ios-error-when-sending-application-specific-file-to-dropbox-using-uidocumentint), which is to add a value for `UTTypeConformsTo`. However, this hasn't helped.

I also read the following discussion [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4489540?start=0&tstart=0) which included:

> The mime type set in the Exported UTI must match up with the mime type
>   of the email attachment. Our plist file had the mime type set to
>   application/octet-stream, but the email was being attached as an
>   application/json mime type. If these don't match, it appears that your
>   application will appear in the "Open with..." menu, but it won't
>   launch your application when you try to open an email attachment.   We
>   switched both to application/json and it fixed the problem.

I understand how the mime type would be set in an email attachment. But I'm opening a file created locally with NSFileManager. Is there some way I have to set mime-type for a local file? Or is this more likely some other problem?

Not sure which of these is the important one, but here's my settings (in the game, not the editor— I'm assuming that the game's Info.plist is the problem because of the error above) for document type:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
                    <string>MyApp Level Pack</string>
                    <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>com.myapp.sslp</string>
                    </array>
                    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                    <string>Viewer</string>
                    <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
                    <string>Owner</string>
                    <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>public.json</string>
                        <string>com.myapp.sslp</string>
                    </array>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>MyApp Level Pack</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.myapp.sslp</string>
                <string>public.json</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

And for Exported Type Declarations:

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>public.data</string>
                        <string>public.json</string>
                    </array>
                    <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
                    <string>MyApp Level Pack</string>
                    <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
                    <string>com.myapp.sslp</string>
                    <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                        <string>sslp</string>
                        <key>public.mime-type</key>
                        <string>application/json</string>
                    </dict>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
                <string>public.json</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>MyApp Level Pack</string>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.myapp.sslp</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Comment: You have a 2nd UTExportedTypeDeclarations nested inside the 1st UTExportedTypeDeclarations. Is that really how your Info.plist is or is this a mistake when posting the question?

Comment: It's really how the Info.plist is built from XCode. I thought it was weird too...

Comment: You have the same problem with your CFBundleDocumentTypes entry. Fix both so there is only one of each and things should work much better.

Comment: Heck yes! Thanks for that good clear eye. (Took a `Reset Simulator` as well, for anyone else having this problem.)